# Finding an equation of a plane a certain distance from a given plane

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, vectors

I just wanted to know the methodology of how to solve for the equation of a plane that is some distance from some given plane.

Thanks. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What are your ideas on this?

Comment: To be completely honest, I am lost. I'm thinking possibly using the distance formula and manipulating it with the general scalar equation and going from there.

Answer (score 2):

If the given plane equation is 
$$ax+by+cz=d$$ 
where $(a,b,c)$ is the **unit normal** then the required equation is 
$$ax+by+cz=d\pm e$$ 
where e is the distance between the planes

## Added

The normal to both planes is $(a,b,c)$ and so the required plane equation is 
$$ax+by+cz=F$$
Then for any point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on this plane we have
$$\color{red}{ax_0+by_0+cz_0}=F$$ 
and the distance $e$ from the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to the given plane is
$$e=\frac{|\color{red}{ax_0+by_0+cz_0}-d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}= \frac{|\color{red}F-d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}
\\ \implies e\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=|F-d|\implies F=d\pm e\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
If the normal is **unit** normal then
$$ax+by+cz=d\pm e$$
***Note*** the distance between a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and a plane $ax+by+cd-d=0$ is given by the formula
$$\color{blue}{\frac{|ax_0+by_0+cz_0-d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}}$$

Comment: could you explain how you arrived at this solution please?

Comment: I have edited the solution

Comment: I still don't understand from the third step on, where u introduced e. Sorry for this. I'm a new student to plane geometry and very confused

Answer (score 0):

If the desired distance is $n$, then the required equation is $ax+by+cz+d\pm n\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=0$.

Comment: Please justify.